# Apple TV YouTube "Error occured loading this content"

Tags: appletv, error, youtube, television

So my YouTube application for my Apple TV is not working. When I go to play a video, it shows "An error has occurred loading this content. Try again later." This first started happening yesterday out of the blue, and I double-checked to see if any of my other applications had the same problem but YouTube's the only one. I've unplugged and plugged back in the cords on the back of the box, and I've restarted Apple TV and still no luck. If anyone has any suggestions, please reply!

Answer (score 2):

1. Start the YouTube application on your Apple TV
2. scroll to the right to "settings" in your menu
3. click "settings" and go to "clear cookies"
4. choose "clear cookies" and start playing your videos again.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. I cleared the cookies in the youtube app and it started working

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you "cleared the cookies in the YouTube app"? As written, this answer is very vague and will likely attract down votes even if it does ultimately solve the problem. Thanks!